# Why doesn't my if statement work in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm working on a simple game that I'm programming in shell for a college assignment and I don't know why my last if doesn't work properly:

```
#! /bin/bash

sort -n num.txt > sorted_nums.txt

pc_num=`head -1 sorted_nums.txt`

read $user_num

if [ $user_num = $pc_num ]
then
      echo "You are correct"
else
      echo "You're wrong, the right answer was $pc_num"
fi
```

The problem comes in the if statement because when I run the programme it will always print the error:

```
./nums.sh: line 9: [: =: binary operator expected
```

I have also tried replacing = with -eq and still doesn't work

And then print:

```
You're wrong, the right answer was $pc_num
```

Thank you!

Comment: try printing the values of $user_num and $pc_num *before* the if. To debug programs, it helps to break them into parts and test them independently of each other

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are being directed to the wrong line. Actually you are reading the user input wrong. It must be `read user_num` without the `$`.